# Fox Pro Error on getting values using MAX(date)

Tags: php, sql, inner-join, adodb, foxpro

I'm in a bind with a deadline and I cannot seem to figure this out.

I am trying to query the table to get the values for the corresponding max shipdate. My query is below. This is for Fox Pro using an ODBC driver.

```
 SELECT
    so1.sono,
    so1.custno,
    so1.item,
    so1.shipdate as last_shipdate,
    so1.price as last_price
FROM sotran01 so1
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                    custno,
                    item,
                    MAX(shipdate) as last_shipdate
            FROM sotran01
            WHERE shipdate >= {d'2013-05-23'}
            AND shipdate <= {d'2014-05-23'}
            GROUP BY custno, item
    ) so2 ON (so1.custno = so2.custno AND so1.item = so2.item AND so1.shipdate = so2.last_shipdate)
WHERE so1.item IN (
    SELECT item
    FROM arpric01
)
ORDER BY so1.custno, so1.item, so1.shipdate
```

This is what I get (using [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/)):

```
ADODB_vfp Object
(
    [databaseType] => vfp
    [fmtDate] => {^Y-m-d}
    [fmtTimeStamp] => {^Y-m-d, h:i:sA}
    [replaceQuote] => '+chr(39)+'
    [true] => .T.
    [false] => .F.
    [hasTop] => top
    [_bindInputArray] => 
    [sysTimeStamp] => datetime()
    [sysDate] => date()
    [ansiOuter] => 1
    [hasTransactions] => 
    [curmode] => 
    [dataProvider] => odbc
    [hasAffectedRows] => 1
    [binmode] => 1
    [useFetchArray] => 
    [_genSeqSQL] => create table %s (id integer)
    [_autocommit] => 1
    [_haserrorfunctions] => 1
    [_has_stupid_odbc_fetch_api_change] => 1
    [_lastAffectedRows] => 0
    [uCaseTables] => 1
    [_dropSeqSQL] => drop table %s
    [database] => 
    [host] => DRIVER={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SOURCETYPE=dbf;SOURCEDB=C:\Sites\hub.fieldfresh.dev\_cache\VP10\PRAXIS\;EXCLUSIVE=NO;
    [user] => 
    [password] => 
    [debug] => 
    [maxblobsize] => 262144
    [concat_operator] => +
    [substr] => substr
    [length] => length
    [random] => rand()
    [upperCase] => upper
    [nameQuote] => "
        [charSet] => 
    [metaDatabasesSQL] => 
    [metaTablesSQL] => 
    [uniqueOrderBy] => 
    [emptyDate] =>  
    [emptyTimeStamp] =>  
    [lastInsID] => 
    [hasInsertID] => 
    [hasLimit] => 
    [readOnly] => 
    [hasMoveFirst] => 
    [hasGenID] => 
    [genID] => 0
    [raiseErrorFn] => 
    [isoDates] => 
    [cacheSecs] => 3600
    [memCache] => 
    [memCacheHost] => 
    [memCachePort] => 11211
    [memCacheCompress] => 
    [sysUTimeStamp] => 
    [arrayClass] => ADORecordSet_array
    [noNullStrings] => 
    [numCacheHits] => 0
    [numCacheMisses] => 0
    [pageExecuteCountRows] => 1
    [uniqueSort] => 
    [leftOuter] => 
    [rightOuter] => 
    [autoRollback] => 
    [poorAffectedRows] => 
    [fnExecute] => 
    [fnCacheExecute] => 
    [blobEncodeType] => 
    [rsPrefix] => ADORecordSet_
    [autoCommit] => 1
    [transOff] => 0
    [transCnt] => 0
    [fetchMode] => 2
    [null2null] => null
    [bulkBind] => 
    [_oldRaiseFn] => 
    [_transOK] => 
    [_connectionID] => Resource id #8
    [_errorMsg] => [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Syntax error.
    [_errorCode] => 37000
    [_queryID] => 
    [_isPersistentConnection] => 
    [_evalAll] => 
    [_affected] => 
    [_logsql] => 
    [_transmode] => 
    [_error] => 
)
```

The error doesn't say much. I can copy and paste the code into MySQL and it runs fine and returns what I expect. Hopefully another set of eyes, with more Fox Pro experience, can see what the issue is here.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is incorrect.  This is the subquery:

```
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT custno, item, MAX(shipdate) as last_shipdate
        FROM sotran01
        WHERE shipdate >= {d'2013-05-23'}
        AND shipdate <= {d'2014-05-23'}
        GROUP BY custno, item, last_shipdate
-------------------------------^
)
```

That is an aggregation column.  Remove it:

```
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT custno, item, MAX(shipdate) as last_shipdate
        FROM sotran01
        WHERE shipdate >= {d'2013-05-23'}
        AND shipdate <= {d'2014-05-23'}
        GROUP BY custno, item
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed that and have the same error. It definitely has to do with the INNER JOIN. If I remove it the query runs fine. There are many limitation with the ODBC. Could the INNER JOIN sub-query not be supported? I'm looking into this now

Comment: Is that date format correct? Doesn't look like a valid VFP format. I'd use {^2014-05-23}